# Has anyone tried integrating RTKLIB into ROS?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Rtklib is a software for the enhancement of precision of data derived from satellite positioning system. I am trying to integrate some features of this software in ROS. I had few questions on this so wanted to know if there is anybody who has worked on it before.

Rtklib information can be found on

```
http://www.rtklib.com/
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/65969/has-anyone-tried-integrating-rtklib-into-ros?/) by [Asfandyar Ashraf Malik](https://answers.ros.org/users/5044/asfandyar-ashraf-malik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 729 on 2013-06-25

Post score: 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, I recently found this package from ETH Zurich:

https://github.com/ethz-asl/rtklibros

You can even find the associated report in the repository: https://github.com/ethz-asl/rtklibros/blob/master/documents/Grieneisen_SA_Final.pdf

I don't know that you should expect centimeter-level accuracy online with something like the uBlox receivers, but it should be better than a single-ended solution.

---

Originally posted by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) with karma: 6414 on 2013-06-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Gudjohnson](https://answers.ros.org/users/5370/gudjohnson/) on 2013-08-05**:
@mjcarroll I am trying to display detected satellites in rviz/tf and I am encountering some problem. As you have worked on this so you might be able to help me here. I have opened the question on this link (http://answers.ros.org/question/70690/failing-to-displaying-information-in-tf/)

**Comment by [jlupdawg](https://answers.ros.org/users/39677/jlupdawg/) on 2019-01-25**:
Hello, I am fairly new to ROS in general and have just finished all of the beginner tutorials. In search for an RTKLIB in ROS I came across this github link and the associated report but I have no clue where to start. Any advice about ROS or this package is helpful!